# Uppercase Keyboard when focusing a TextInput

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, textinput

I have a `TextInput` field in react-native and I set `autofocus` to `true` so it automatically opens the keyboard when loaded.

What I want is that it opens a keyboard in uppercase letters (not only for the first characters, I want the uppercase key to be enabled so all letters are uppercase when typing)

[image]

According to the [TextInput documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) I can specify which kind of keyboard to use with the `keyboardType` prop.

There are several keyboards available: default, email, numeric, phone...

However none of them do what I want :(

How can I force the keyboard to be uppercase when focusing a TextInput?

Comment: try: `<TextInput autoCapitalize='characters' ...`

Comment: Cherniv, this worked and is the easiest solution, if you put it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: it is ok , glad if it helps

Answer (score 20):

I overlooked Cherniv's comment when I was first here and ended up finding the same solution, so I'll make it an answer to give it more visibility.

`<TextInput autoCapitalize='characters' />`

Answer (score -1):

Use this `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`

(OR)

Set the `input type` to  `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT| TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS`. The keyboard should honor that.